# DuckDB - Rank correlation is much slower than regular correlation

Tags: python, sql, duckdb

Comparing the following two code sections with the only difference as the second one first computes `rank`, the second section results in much slower performance than the first one (~5x).

Although the second section involves a few more extra computations (`rank`), I don't expect and understand such a big difference. Am I implementing the query very inefficiently (I don't so as well because I think DuckDB should have query optimizations in place)?

Note: Similar computations using Polars will not result in such a big slow down (code not shown here, otherwise people will be overwhelmed with too many codes).

```
import time

import duckdb
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

## example dataframe
rng = np.random.default_rng(1)

nrows = 5_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    dict(
        id=rng.integers(1, 1_000, nrows),
        id2=rng.integers(1, 10, nrows),
        id3=rng.integers(1, 500, nrows),
        v1=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
        v2=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
    )
)

## pearson correlation
start = time.perf_counter()
res = duckdb.sql(
    """
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT df.id2, df.id3, df2.id3 AS id3_right,
            df.v1, df2.v1 AS v1_right,
            df.v2, df2.v2 AS v2_right
        FROM df
        JOIN df AS df2
        ON (
            df.id = df2.id
            AND df.id2 = df2.id2
            AND df.id3 > df2.id3
            AND df.id3 < df2.id3 + 30
        )
    )
    SELECT id2, id3, id3_right, corr(v1, v1_right) AS v1, corr(v2, v2_right) AS v2
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY id2, id3, id3_right
    """
).pl()
time.perf_counter() - start
# 19.462523670867085

## rank correlation
start = time.perf_counter()
res2 = duckdb.sql(
    """
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT df.id2, df.id3, df2.id3 AS id3_right,
            RANK() OVER (g ORDER BY df.v1) AS v1,
            RANK() OVER (g ORDER BY df2.v1) AS v1_right,
            RANK() OVER (g ORDER BY df.v2) AS v2,
            RANK() OVER (g ORDER BY df2.v2) AS v2_right
        FROM df
        JOIN df AS df2
        ON (
            df.id = df2.id
            AND df.id2 = df2.id2
            AND df.id3 > df2.id3
            AND df.id3 < df2.id3 + 30
        )
        WINDOW g AS (PARTITION BY df.id2, df.id3, df2.id3)
    )
    SELECT id2, id3, id3_right, corr(v1, v1_right) AS v1, corr(v2, v2_right) AS v2
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY id2, id3, id3_right
    """
).pl()
time.perf_counter() - start
# 104.54312287131324
```

Comment: Rank is slow as alpst Eve y window function but doing it manually was even slower and you have 4 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank correlation query computes `RANK()` in four different windows, each of which requires partitioning and sorting the data set. There is an optimisation here that could be done to share the partitioning and only re-sort, but that has not been implemented. It may not make a difference, however, as the partitions will be re-read on separate threads would likely just end up being copied. Also, partitioning is linear, so the sorting would likely dominate. `RANK()` is also peer-sensitive, and I suspect that the current implementation is suboptimal.

It might be a better approach for you to file these questions/issues with the DuckDB issue tracking system on GitHub instead of asking the entire world to answer highly technical questions about the internals that only about 3 people can answer? If you did that we could have a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thanks. I am not an experienced user on either SQL or DuckDB. So, just decided to ask here first to see whether the slowness comes from some naive mistakes or mis-understandings of DuckDB/SQL.

Comment: No worries! We do appreciate the questions and can bring up such issues here: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues